# Confused by memory swap of pointers

Tags: c, pointers

The function `swap2` has two parameters, `int *a`, and `int *b`. These are pointers to pointers to integer values. So why when in `swap2` you execute lines such as `int tmp = *a; *a = *b;` does it change the memory location of these values. Wouldn't the `*` deference the pointers that were declared in the parameters?

```
int main()
{
        int x = 42;
        int y = 9;
        printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
        swap1(x,y);
        printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
        x = 42, y = 9;
        swap2(&x, &y);
        printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
        printf("---\n");
        int z = 77, w = 33;
        int *p = &z;
        int *q = &w;

        printf("*p = %d, *q = %d, p = %p, q = %p\n", *p, *q, p, q);
        swap2(p,q);

        z = 77, w = 33;
        printf("*p = %d, *q = %d, p = %p, q = %p\n", *p, *q, p, q);
        swap3(&p, &q);
        printf("*p = %d, *q = %d, p = %p, q = %p\n", *p, *q, p, q);

        printf("z = %d, w = %d\n", z, w);

        return 0;
}

void swap1(int a, int b)
{
        int tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp,
        printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
}

void swap2(int *a, int *b)
{
        int tmp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = tmp;
        printf("*a = %d, *b = %d\n", *a, *b);
}

void swap3(int **a, int **b)
{
        int *tmp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = tmp;
        printf("**a = %d, **b = %d\n", **a, **b);
}
```

Comment: `swap3` takes pointer *to pointer* to integer, there are two levels there.

Comment: swap1 is useless, the only effect is printing of the diagnostic. swap2 is standard swapping of `int`s (+ diagnostic). swap3 is swapping of `int*`s, the diagnostic is not the best though... Anyway, you can leave the forward-declarations (together with the includes in the omitted head of the source-file, I sincerely hope) out if you define the functions and use them afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

`swap2 (int *a, int *b)` won't change any memory location, it change what `a` and `b` is pointing to, when you call `swap2(&x, &y)`, your memory schema will looks like the following:

```
                             int x
[a (address of x)] ->  [actual x = 42]

                             int y
[b (address of y)] ->  [actual y = 9]
```

int tmp = *a;

```
[tmp = (deference address of x) = actual x = 42]
```

*a = *b;

```
                                        int x
[a (address of x)] ->  [deference b => actual y => 9]
```

*b = tmp;

```
                                    int y
[b (address of y)] ->  [tmp => actual x => 42]
```

---

Since `swap3(int ** a, int **b)` takes "pointer to pointer to an int", the memory schema of a (and b) will looks like the following:

```
                           int * p
[a (some address 1)] -> [another address A'] -> [real integer value A'']

                           int * q
[b (some address 2)] -> [another address B'] -> [real integer value B'']
```

So when you deference a, you actually get an [another address], that's why you're actually change the memory location instead of actual value.

When you execute int *tmp = *a, since you deference a in right hand side, now its value will be "another address A`", the memory schema will become:

```
[tmp (another address A')] -> [real integer value A'']
```

execute *a = *b, you are actually doing this, notice that `a`'s value did not change, you only change the memory it's point to:

```
                             int * p
[a (some address 1)] -> [another address B'] -> [real integer value B'']
```

Finally, *b = tmp, also notice that `b`'s value did not change:

```
                             int * q
[b (some address 2)] -> [another address A'] -> [real integer value A'']
```

Comment: Note that the question has morphed while you were busy answering a previous version.  It appears that `swap2()` is causing confusion, let alone `swap3()`.

Comment: I actually understand swap3(). But I am confused as to why swap2() changes the values of x and y after it is ran.